# Installing Planet CLI?

Tags: installation, planet

As a total Python newbie, I'm trying to install the Planet CLI  on my Windows 7 (64-bit) machine so that I can ultimately use the Planet API to clip and download imagery to my particular area of interest. When I visit the Planet Help page I can see that Planet recommends installing with the following command:

```
pip install planet
```

Into what interface do I type this command? e.g. is there a specific program I need to have downloaded first?

Comment: What Operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 7, 64-bit

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would help you to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Answer (score 2):

You need a recent version of python, i.e 3.6. f you must use Python 2.7, version 2.7.9 or later has pip installed by default.

Open a command prompt (cmd.exe on windows) and type:

```
pip install planet
```

If that doesn't work, you need to type the full path to pip, ie

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip install planet
```

Comment: I downloaded Python 3.6.2 and tried both command prompts. With the first, the return is: 

    pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command

When I try to find the pip file on the hard drive (so that I can type in the full path), however, I can't locate any folder that contains a \Scripts folder with a pip file in it. I have a C:\Python27 folder, but all it contains is a folder called ArGIS10.3. Any other suggestions of what that path might look like? Perhaps I did the install incorrectly.

Comment: There is only one "command prompt" on Windows - cmd.exe (not counting powershell). Try C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Scripts\pip. Python 3.6 installs to somewhere in the C:\Program Files\ (or C:\Program Files (x86)\ for 32 bit python)